# When does ActiveMQ Artemis clean up the group id map

Tags: activemq-artemis

When grouping messages using the `JMSXGroupId` property the broker needs to keep a 'map' of groupId values and consumers to assure all messages with the same `JMSXGroupId` are sent to the same consumer.

We noticed the group count size on the server reduces only when we disconnect consumers.

In a happy case our consumers live for a long time because there is no reason to close the connection of a message listener. This results in increasing group count figure. Is there a way to configure an expiration time for group ids? Or other way to reduce the group map without the need for consumers to reconnect at regular time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got 3 options here (in no particular order)...

First, you can use group "buckets." This essentially reduces the size of the map by using buckets instead of a 1:1 mapping for the group-id/consumer. Additional details and configuration info is available in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/message-grouping.html#group-buckets).

Second, you can configure a `LOCAL` `grouping-handler` with a `group-timeout` which will remove map entries if the group ID isn't used for the configured amount of time. For example:

```xml
<grouping-handler name="my-grouping-handler">
   <type>LOCAL</type>
   <group-timeout>60000</group-timeout>
</grouping-handler>
```

With this configuration any group ID that isn't used for a minute (i.e. 60,000 milliseconds) will be removed.

Third, you can manually close a group by setting the `JMSXGroupSeq` property on the last message in the group to `-1`. This is also discussed in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/message-grouping.html#closing-a-message-group).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it.

Comment: finally we decided not to use groups as it had unwanted side effects but I your answer is the valid one to my question. Thanks.